# zend framework 2 tablegateway select erroring out

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, zend-framework2

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_points' in 'where clause'

protected $tableGateway;

```
public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}


public function fetchPoints$transaction_number)
{
  $results = $this->tableGateway->select(
        array('total_points' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("sum(points)")),
        array('trxnumber' => $transaction_number)
    );
    return $results[0]['total_points'];
}
```

where is it trying to get the total_points column from? I thought points is the column and total_points is the alyias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select only accepts one argument "where". your current query is :

```
select * from my_table where total_points=sum(points)
```

witch is throwing the expected error. i am guesting that you want to :

```
select sum(points) as total_points from my_table where trxnumber=X
```

in this case you should do this :

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$select
    ->columns(array('total_points' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("sum(points)")))
    ->where(array('trxnumber' => $transaction_number));
$result = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
```